# SELECT INTO with SELECT FOR UPDATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, isolation-level

Assume I have a `message` relation where I save messages that was created with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE message 
(
     id serial primary key, 
     foo1 integer, 
     foo2 integer, 
     foo3 text
)
```

And we have a function that gets a message and deletes it from the relation, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_and_delete_message(p_foo1 integer)
RETURNS TABLE(r_id integer, r_foo1 integer, r_foo2 integer, r_foo3 text) AS $$
DECLARE
  message_id integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO message_id FROM message WHERE foo1 = p_foo1 LIMIT 1;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM message WHERE foo1 = p_foo1 LIMIT 1;
    DELETE FROM message where id = message_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Assuming [`READ_COMMITTED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) isolation level it could be that two concurrent transactions from two users return the same message, although obviously only ones deletes/gets it. This is not the desired behavior for my application, I want one message to be read by only one user.

Assuming [`REPEATABLE_READ`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) this wouldn't happen.

But after reading about [`FOR UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) I thought perhaps it's still possible to use `READ_COMMITTED` level and change the `get_and_delete_message` function as following:

```
   ...
    BEGIN
        SELECT id INTO message_id FROM message WHERE foo1 = p_foo1 LIMIT 1;
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM message WHERE foo1 = p_foo1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
        DELETE FROM message where id = message_id;
    END;
    ...
```

From my understanding, using `FOR UPDATE` in the second `SELECT` will actually lock the returned rows until the end of the transaction, so if we have 2 concurrent transactions only one will actually return and delete the message.

Is this the case? Or should I also do `SELECT id INTO message_id FROM message WHERE foo1 = p_foo1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`? I couldn't find any information on combining [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-selectinto.html) with `FOR UPDATE`. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a single statement, no need for a select:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_and_delete_message(p_foo1 integer)
RETURNS TABLE(r_id integer, r_foo1 integer, r_foo2 integer, r_foo3 text) 
AS $$
  DELETE FROM message 
    where foo1 = p_foo1 
  returning *;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

This will delete the rows and then return all deleted rows as a result of the `delete` statement.

Comment: Is this in `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level going to guarantee me that no 2 concurrent transactions return the same message? Something more: Actually I tried to keep my question's example simple so I have `SELECT ... ORDER BY` and it seems it's not possible to do the same with `DELETE`.

At the end your answer doesn't really answer my questions :S, though I really appreciate the time you took to answer